# How to implement datasource for a datatable in Angular 5

Tags: json, angular, material-design, angular-datatables

I been trying to follow all the tutorials, and answers that I have found and I just can't make it work yet. Any help is appreciated it. I got this error:

> Error: Provided data source did not match an array, Observable, or DataSource

And this is the JSON response I get from the server:

```
{receivedDate: "2018-05-22T00:00:00", id: "27280371", companyName: "Dark&Stormy", documentType: 11, receipts: Array(1), …}
```

And this is my code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpRequest, HttpEventType, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import { MatPaginator, MatSort, MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';

import { myService } from './../../../api';
import { InputService } from './../input.service';

import { IReceipt } from './../models/receipt.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-submission-details',
  templateUrl: './submission-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./submission-details.component.css']
})
export class SubmissionDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  setPaymentMethodForm: FormGroup;
  submissionList = [];
  errorMessage: string;
  private documentId;

  receipt: IReceipt;

  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
  displayedColumnsReceipt = ['id', 'fromDate', 'pReference', 'pMethod', 'status', 'valid', 'receipt'];

  constructor(
    private client: myService.Client,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private inputService: InputService,
    private router: Router,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
  ) { 
      this.createForm();
      activatedRoute.data
      .subscribe(
        data => this.documentId = data[this.documentId]
      );
    }

  id: string;
  private document: any;

  ngOnInit() {

    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
      if (params['id']) {
        this.id = params['id'];
        console.log('paramsId: ', this.id);
        this.inputService.getDocumentId(this.id)
        .subscribe(res => {
          this.dataSource = res;
          console.log('sub-details.res: ', res);
        });
      }
    });
  }

  getSubmissionDetails(string): void {
    this.client.apiSubmissionGetSubmissionDocumentGet('documentId')
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.submissionList = this.submissionList;
          console.log('data: ', data);
        },
        (error: any) => this.errorMessage = <any> error);
  }

  createForm() {
    this.setMethodForm = this.fb.group({
      documentId: '',
      receiptType: ''
    });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here

```
this.dataSource = res;
```

Whats `res`? Is it array? If so then

```
this.dataSource.data = res;
```

Comment: it's component and therefore I think is the error about not been an array.

Comment: Well obviously you need to provide data not, component. Extract data and assign as shown above.

Comment: I meant a JSON component :) like: {receivedDate: "2018-05-22T00:00:00", id: "27280371", companyName: "Dark&Stormy", documentType: 11, receipts: Array(1), …} As you can see, is not in [ ... ]

Comment: @Probandt I don't care what it is, you just need array. Each element must will be used as row data supplier. *I meant a JSON component* - NO, its just JSON

Comment: I got this: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed